# Attempted to commit to a bad inbox level while publish commitment in tezos sandbox mode

Tags: tezos-client, sandbox, testnet

I am new to tezos. I am trying sandbox mode.I send an outbox message to rollup using octez client command.I tried to get the messages using this command:
**$ octez-smart-rollup-client-${PROTO} rpc get 

/global/block/cemented/outbox/${L}/messages**
but it is returing an empty list [].
so while searching for the issue i found the outbox is not cemented yet and needto commit and cement. so i tried to commit the message using
**$ publish commitment from src for smart rollup smart rollup address with compressed state compressed_state at inbox level inbox_level and predecessor predecessor and number of ticks number_of_ticks**
but it is giving error

**Node is bootstrapped.
This simulation failed:
Manager signed operations:
From: tz1KqTpEZ7Yob7QbPE4Hy4Wo8fHG8LhKxZSx
Fee to the baker: ꜩ0
Expected counter: 5
Gas limit: 1040000
Storage limit: 60000 bytes
Smart rollup commitment publishing:
Address: sr1NYzwSCydrisYKjHk7zvqXS9qEyWc7CT9G
Commitment:
compressed_state: srs12zvm65HDz67eZX8SuSfksoUwdvLr8VQhYLUcyzAE992Mk2Nwmx
inbox_level: 5
predecessor: src13E7huXgcdU2dmQ1wfycBvjeaPY6WeJzAeqEgbeQTHQ79VFhCr8
number_of_ticks: 99000000000
This operation FAILED.
Error:
Attempted to commit to a bad inbox level.**
what is the issue here? is there any mistake in my steps . or do i need to just for the commitment to happend for 2 weeks . that i saw somewhere in the official documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A commitment is for an given period (60 blocks on mainnet). Each commitment must be for exactly that period since the predecessor commitment. The inbox level you provide in the commitment must be the correct one, based on the predecessor commitment.

Are you using a rollup node to run your kernel? The rollup node job, in `operator|maintenance` mode  is to do all the "administrative" work for your rollup, i.e. publish commitment, cement them....

Comment: yes. i am using rollup node in operator mode. then why i am not getting outbox message on rpc get
/global/block/cemented/outbox/${L}/messages. I am using local testnet.